# How do i properly install ANTLRDT in eclpse?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've downloaded [ANTLRDT](http://www.certiv.net/projects/antlrdt.html), but for some reason its not showing on my eclipse. my Eclipse version is Eclipse 2018-09. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Proper installation of any Eclipse plugin can be verified by going to `Help`→`About`→`Installed Software`.

The `AntlrDT` preference pages are located at `Window`→`Preferences`→`Certiv Tools`→`AntlrDT`.

Typical source/grammar layout:

```
<workspace root>
   <project root>
      /snippets.test/
          /some.txt       // the source text file to parse
      /src/main/java/
          /my/package/path/
               /parser/
                   MyParser.g4
                   MyLexer.g4
                   /gen/
```

Corresponding grammar header block:

```
@header {
    package my.package.path.parser.gen ;
}
```

Updated:

```
<workspace root>
   <testgrammar>
      /snippets.test/
          /hello.txt       // the source text file to parse
      /src/
          /build/
             /parser/
                Hello.g4
                /gen/
```

Add this grammar header block in `Hello.g4`:

```
@header {
    package build.parser.gen ;
}
```

Comment: Yes its there, but the tokens and Paths view are no where to be found, on my toolbar in eclipse.

Comment: Those toolbar elements will only be visible when an Antlr `.g4` grammar is open in the editor. Be sure that the grammar is in a valid source package for your target language. Be sure to add a proper header block to the grammar containing a valid source package statement -- where the Antlr generated files are to be placed.

Comment: I've opened the Hello.g4 file that comes with ANTLR4 download. still nothing.

Comment: Are you opening it specifically with the AntlrDT editor? In the Package Explorer, right-click on the grammar file and choose `Open with`.  Also, do you have another Antlr editor installed? If so, remove it.

Comment: i did then i got error. 
**Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'net.certiv.antlrdt.core.builder'.
Plug-in "net.certiv.antlrdt.core" was unable to instantiate class "net.certiv.antlrdt.core.builder.AntlrDTBuilder".
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/OrganizeImportsOperation$IChooseImportQuery
Plug-in "net.certiv.antlrdt.core" was unable to instantiate class "net.certiv.antlrdt.core.builder.AntlrDTBuilder".
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/OrganizeImportsOperation$IChooseImportQuery**

Comment: Apparently you do not have the JDT installed.

Comment: What JDT? I simply followed the instructions and downloaded ANTLRDT from the marketplace

Comment: By default, Antlr generates Java source code. In order to do anything with it, you need to have the Java Development Tools (JDT) installed.

Comment: THen i should already have it? Their code generated for the grammar

Comment: I managed to have the token view select the correct grammar, how do i get it to select the correct source? right now theres nothing there and i keep getting some kind of workbench error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181644/discussion-between-grosenberg-and-user2333103).